# Laravel does not redirect to other directions on Ubuntu Server Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, deployment

im currently developing a web platform but when I run my webpage on the server only welcome page can be viewed, I can not login or register o go to another page because shows me The requested URL was not found on this server.
Can you help me?
and my config apache file is   [image]
[image]

my .htaccess is

Comment: This is way too broad as it stands, since you don't show any code or configuration. You'll need to make sure your htaccess file is correct per Laravel's needs, as well as making sure the paths are correct.

Comment: Sounds like your apache server is not configured correctly. Can you post your apache configuration?

Comment: We need some code or at least some sort of configuration in order to help you. There can be any number or things generating this error.

Comment: My config file in apache has inside <Directory /var/www/apps/forms> Option Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverrida All Required all granted </Directory>  and my .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe run in your terminal `a2enmod rewrite`?.
2. Did you try running `php artisan serve`?

If error is only with login and register, did you ensure that `routes/web.php` has auth line `Auth::routes();`?